# Make users of my library to call function with primitive values and class names as well

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have got an untypical requirement. I'm writing a setup library function, which should be called with only constant values and class names. I made something like this:

```
template <unsigned index, class layerClass, typename...Args>
void setup_layers() {
     //add layer
     //recursively call yourself
     setup_layers<Args...>();
}

template <unsigned index, class layerClass>
void setup_layers() {
     //add layer
}
```

When I try use my function:

```
struct MyLayer {};


int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    constexpr unsigned LAYER_NUM = 0;
    setup_layers<LAYER_NUM, MyLayer>();
    return 0;
}
```

the compiler reports the error `call of overloaded ‘setup_layers<LAYER_NUM, MyLayer>()’ is ambiguous`

I'm not sure how can I accomplish my requirement in the other way :(. If I could pass class names as parameters to my function via normal arguments it would be fine, but C++ has no such feature...

**EDIT**
OK, it seems my "solution" goes nowhere and simply doesn't work.
Because I don't want to delete a question with answers, then maybe I should ask my question differently:

I want users of my library to set a list of layers with indexes (where numbers in those indexes doesn't have to have consecutive numbers). The reason why I wanted to do it using templates is because templates can allow only constant values as parameters. To put it simply: I want to forbid my users from using variables as parameters for indexes.

Comment: @Peter Done, but still I get the same error :(

Comment: You are not passing any integral value to `setup_layers<Args...>()`. If the template needs one, you must pass one.

Comment: @Peter No this is not the case (says `std::array<int, 5>`).

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm using G++9 and I must admit the error compiler reports is actually "no matching function for call to setup_layers" but as a reason for this it gives me note with explanation as I gave

Comment: @TedLyngmo OK I tried to isolate the error and made a test program and yes now the compiler error reports are different. Mea culpa... But the point of my question still stays the same: my program doesn't compile :(. I'm using C++20 standard.

Comment: @Felix.leg Regarding your edited question: What are those, possibly non-consecutive, indices used for? Should every use of the same layer class have the same index?

Comment: @TedLyngmo as keys in a map. I want them to be constant for the whole program lifetime. I want to let my users assign them arbitrarily using constexpr-s, so when they need to refer to them later in the program they can use those constexpr-s. I don't know how can I make my users not to change their mind in the middle of a program and reassign these values again. I'm really not sure if I can do that, and I wanted to delete my question, but SO said I may lose privileges to ask questions forever :O.

Comment: Ok, so `MyLayer` should have the same index in the map everytime it's used then?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes.

Comment: @Felix.leg Ok, I added an option for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option to resolve the ambiguity: You could rename the function doing the actual setup implementation. I've called it `setup_impl`:

```
template <unsigned index, class layerClass>
void setup_impl() {
    //add layer
    std::cout << index << '\n';
}

template <unsigned index, class layerClass, class... Args>
void setup_layers() {
    setup_impl<index, layerClass>();
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) > 0) {
        setup_layers<index + 1, Args...>();
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9vqnr5qM6)

If `index` is supposed to be the same every time a Layer class is used, you could make the `index` a property of the Layer classes.

Example:

```
template <class layerClass>
void setup_impl() {
    std::cout << layerClass::index << '\n';
}

template <class... Args>
void setup_layers() {
    (setup_impl<Args>(), ...); // fold expression
}

struct MyLayer1 { static constexpr unsigned index = 11; };
struct MyLayer2 { static constexpr unsigned index = 22; };
struct MyLayer3 { static constexpr unsigned index = 33; };
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sME4jWzKo)

Comment: After rethinking I decided your solution may be the only workable one. Thank you for your patience (there were a lot of it). :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors.

1. `setup_layers<Args...>();` doesn't pass any integral template argument to `setup_layers`. There is no definition of `setup_layers` that doesn't have an `unsigned` value template parameter at the first position, so this call doesn't match anything. Try e.g. `setup_layers<index+1, Args...>()>;` instead.
2. The two overloads are ambiguous when there is exactly one type parameter passed.

   ```
    template <unsigned index, class layerClass, typename...Args> ...
    template <unsigned index, class layerClass /*, nothing   */> ...
   ```

   An empty `typename ... Args` pack is legitimate and there is no reason to prefer an empty parameter pack over nothing, or vice versa. Try removing `class layerClass` from the second overload (and have it do nothing). `template <unsigned index> void setup_layers() {}` should do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <int index, class layerClass>
void setup_layers(int layer) {
    //add layer
    std::cout << "Adding layer " << layer << ": " << typeid(layerClass).name() << std::endl;
}

template <class layerClass, typename...Args>
void setup_layers(int layer) {
    //add layer
    //recursively call yourself
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) > 0) {
        setup_layers<0, layerClass>(++layer);
        setup_layers<Args...>(layer);
    } else {
        setup_layers<0, layerClass>(layer);
    }
}

struct MyLayer {};
struct OtherLayer {};

int main() {
    setup_layers<MyLayer, OtherLayer, MyLayer, OtherLayer>(0);
    std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Adding layer 1: 7MyLayer
Adding layer 2: 10OtherLayer
Adding layer 3: 7MyLayer
Adding layer 3: 10OtherLayer
End
```

Comment: One question: does ```typename...Args``` can only expand to class names? Because I want my list to contains mixed list of arguments with both indexes and class names, as I not always want to initialize my layers with consecutive numbers. If this is impossible, then I should really rethink my "solution" and try something different (and also delete this post so to no shame myself more...) :(

Comment: No.  You can't mix indexes and class names in `Args`. You could pass the indexes as a variadic parameter to the function... but that complicates things.

Comment: @Felix.leg What do you want to *do* with a mix of indices and class names?